# Relation between annihilator of kernel and range of the transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, duality-theorems

> Let $A:X\to Y$ be a continuous linear map.
>
> Let $A^*:Y^*\to X^*$ denote the transpose of $A$ (also referred to as the dual transformation of $A$)
>
> Let $\ker A ^⊥$ denote the annihilator of $\ker A$.
>
> 1) Prove that $\overline{\text{im} A^*}\subset\ker A ^⊥$
>
> 2) Setting $X=Y=l_1$ and $A:(u_n)\to \left(\frac{u_n}{n}\right)$, prove that $\overline{\text{im} A^*}\subsetneq\ker A ^⊥$

While the first question is very easy to deal with using the very definitions of $A^*$ and $\ker A ^⊥$, I'm stuck with the second question.

Since $\ker A = {0}$, we have $\ker A ^⊥=l_1^*$, so it boils down to finding some $f\in l_1^*\simeq l_\infty$ such that $f\notin \overline{\text{im} A^*}$.

I can't really picture what ${\text{im} A^*}$ is, so that makes finding the convenient $f$ really hard for me.

Comment: Start by figuring out what $A^{\ast}$ is. With a description of $A^{\ast}$, it becomes rather easy to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer If $(e_i)$ denotes the elementary sequence $(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$, then $A^*$ can be thought of as the object that maps the sequence $(g(e_i))\in l_\infty$ to $(\frac{g(e_i)}{i})\in l_\infty$. But that's not insightful for me.

Comment: What is $g$ here? If you have a sequence $s = (s_1, s_2, s_3, \dotsc) \in l_{\infty}$, what is $A^{\ast}(s)$? (Identifying $l_{\infty}$ with $(l_1)^{\ast}$)